# Entityspaces and Ncache

Tags: c#, ncache, entityspaces

I'm sorry this is probably a borderline poor question. Does anyone have experience using write-through/read-through ncache with entityspaces?

I also tried searching for implementations of wt/rt providers for nhibernate and ncache to possibly roll my own for entityspaces, but I wasn't able to find any sample code. Is there any code that could be shared (or links) that would get me started with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for late reply.As per following post by EntitySpaces employee on their forum,they do not support caching to begin with.
http://www.entityspaces.net/portal/Forums/tabid/203/forumid/20/postid/5461/scope/posts/Default.aspx

However, it seems that EntitySpaces also makes use of ADO.net Provider and we do caching at ADO.net level in Entity Framework in NCache.
But we also do not provide any direct implementation/wrapper for EntitySpaces yet.